# Enable Repeated Qualtrics Survey Taking by the same user

Tags: qualtrics

I want to enable a single survey taker to retake my Qualtrics survey repeatedly on the same device, an iPhone, about 100 times in 3 hours.  That person will be collecting data on a single mobile device for about 100 subjects.  I would like that researcher to be able to submit the survey for each subject, then start a new survey repeatedly.  Qualtrics reports that it would be possible if the person clears the mobile device's web browser cookies, but that has not worked in testing.  Also, that would be too time consuming over hundreds of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue.  Under Survey Options make sure "Prevent Ballot Box Stuffing" is NOT checked and the survey is set to "Open Access".

If you have "Save & Continue" checked, the researcher needs to make sure they get all the way to the end of the survey (end of survey message or redirect) before starting a new one.

You can set the redirect to point back to the survey to re-start or put a link back to the survey in the end of survey message.

Optionally, you may want to use an authenticator block and put all the other blocks inside it.  In that case, you would set up a panel (contact list) with id numbers (one for each respondent) that the researcher would use to authenticate.

Comment: Thank you T.  The redirect link worked and cookies are not an issue.